# Is the 'return' path / switch needed?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, switches

**Short question**

Is the circuit functionally equal, with the yellow switches always in 'closed' state? (Each yellow switch is a 2DP switch together with the switch left of it)

**Background**

I'm creating a guitar pedal Fuzz effect, based on Randofo's Instructable, see the picture.
https://www.instructables.com/id/The-Fuzz-of-1000-Faces/

The red cross and resistor on the right (marked in red) is an 'enhancement' how the circuit should be.

The original idea is to use for the selection of the 2 x 6 switches (the combination of the yellow marked and the ones left of it) to use 2P6P rotary switches.

I want to use (analog) multiplexers, to control them digitally.

Current, I'm using CD4052's to handle 4 transistors by one CD4052, where one channel is just for the yellow switch, and one for the switch left of the yellow.

However, I'm wondering if the yellow switches are needed at all. Reason is that it doesn't matter if current flows into the transistor's collector, because if the transistor's base (same 'switch signal') doesn't get any current, the collector's signal will not be forwarded to the emitter anyway.

So, is the circuit functionally equal, to remove the yellow switches? (and assume it's a continuous path) ?

(as a side remark, someone gave me a tip to use analog switch array's which I'm probably going to use).
[image]

**Analysis**

Because of Andy Aka's useful comment to try Micro-cap 12 which I installed, I did some analysis, but I don't understand why the results are as they show.

I made the following (minimalistic) circuit:

[image]

I set V2 to DC 4.5 V, and amplitude 4.5V, to get values between 0-9V.

What can be seen is that the emitter of the transistor is 3.879V.
In the Fuzz normally switch 2 and 4 are tied together (SPDT), similar as switch 3 and 5, but I want for analysis to control them separate.

When I however also connect switch 5, the result of the voltage of the transistor's emitters is still 3.879 V ... so far so good. 
And when I only select switch 5, I get 3.878 V.

So the result is that it doesn't matter if I remove switch 4 and 5.

However, when I tried NONE of the switches, so no collector is attached anywhere, it still shows 3.878 V.

[image]

So how is this possible? This would mean I don't have to connect anything at the collector? This seems strange to me.

**Analysis 2**

Now I simulated a full chain (using 1 capacitor, 1 transistor, 1 transistor, 1 capacitor).

The input I set to Amplitude 0.5V, DC 1V (to get a s ignal between 0.5 and 1.5V).

Transient Analysis

[image]

[image]

Dynamic DC

[image]

Comment: Have you got a simulator that you could try it out on Michel?

Comment: @Andyaka Well maybe I can use the free version of Proteus (if I have the name right) ... I cannot save, so it will take quite some time to simulate with e.g. two transistors instead of 6 and 1 capacitor.

Comment: Take the plunge and download [microcap 12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) - it is now free and is superb and pi$$es on LTSpice IMHO.

Comment: @AndyAka Thanks, I will try it out this evening.

Comment: There is a learning curve but, if there's anything that I would advise anyone in electronic design, it is to operate a decent simulator.

Comment: @Andyaka I did an online electronics course, which used Proteus (so I should have known to use that), not sure if that is based on SPICE though. But I also will check microcap; if that one is free and friendly to use, it would be great.

Comment: @Andyaka I like this simulator, thanks for the advice. Learning curve was not big, but I'm afraid I don't understand transistors so well, or I made a stupid mistake... I added some analysis in the update of my question, but it puzzles me.

Comment: You need to be decoupling with a capacitor at the input. Just try the set-up in microcap with one transistor in each bank just to prove that you get signal continuity from left to right. No need to use switches. Run transient simulation or dynamic DC (I think you might be running dynamic DC at the moment).

Comment: @Andyaka thanks I will do that ... however, I need either to check if it matters if two collectors from each bank are connected (to see if I need the switch or not in my final design). I used now transient simulation. I will also check what the other simulation types mean (simulation is quite new for me). Not sure if I have time this evening to finish everything.

Comment: Good luck - it is the right way to go (at least it's the way that I would go).

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks ... I'm sure you know better than me :-), so I gladly take your advice.

Comment: @Andyaka It took not that long to create a full chain. I put the result in Analysis 2. However, the result bothers me.  I didn't even check what happens if I add multiple transistor's collector to be tied together. As you can see both in Transient analysis and Dynamic DC analysis, voltages are really low, which I wouldn't expect.

Comment: Try replacing the pots (I never use them) with fixed values of resistance such as 100 kohm for X3. I suspect that the pots are not setup correctly for normal operation looking at the voltages on the bases of the transistors. Replace all the pots.

Comment: @AndyAka .. I tried but it doesn't make a difference. There is by the way a setting PERCENTAGE that defines the value, together with the POTSIZE (100K) parameter.

Comment: You have to try getting the basic amplifier to work. Is your 9 volt battery actually grounded - I can't tell because of the node labels you have? I don't think it is based on the node voltages I see.

Comment: @Andyaka I think that was it, feeling so stupid now.  Anyway, I got now much more sensible results, thank you very much for seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be getting when you simulate the basic circuit is this: -

[image]

I have just used a single resistor of 2 kohm at Q1's emitter and things look right. All the voltages and currents look good to me and I also did a quick check using a 1 kHz source at 10 mV peak and it's producing heavy distortion (as expected and required).

I think you didn't connect your 9 volt source.

Comment: Yes, feeling so stupid I forgot the GND, I get different values as I use different pot values, but they look much like yours.

Comment: It's so easy to change resistor values I just never use pots. See how quick I did it - you'll be at this speed in a few months.

Comment: well to draw it also didn't take me long, just the circuit is too big too analyze to see such basic problems.... next time I start smaller and slowly expand. At least I can do now my 'real' test (checking multiple collectors)

Comment: One thing to note - my R2 value - I chose that so that the voltage at the collector of my_Q1 is at roughly half the supply rail. OK 6 volts is not quite middle but it's near enough. Stick with 2 kohm and see how much the DC output level changes when different transistors are used - it might cause asymmetrical clipping that might indeed be one of the "nice things" about this fuzz box i.e. it colours the sound differently.

Comment: you seem to also know a lot about fuzz pedals (I'm not a guitarist myself btw). Yesterday I drew the entire model (using like 2x8 capacitors and 2x14 transistors), but I haven't had the time to pick all transistors/caps I want to use.

Comment: However, what I saw was that the Transient Analysis did not matter that much depending on the transistor (but it might be in the details). And I also connected all committers together (per bank), and it made a very small change (connecting all 14 means like 0.2 V difference). Maybe that's too much, maybe not, so I need in the weekend to perform more tests.

Comment: Aha - I am a guitarist hence my knowledge of fuzz pedals and distortion. Hard to say if those differences matter realistically.

Comment: I hope so ... well anyway I like learning about electronics, only the guitarist of the band(s) I play in might not like the end result when so many transistors doesn't matter. Although I have been before Corona to him with trying out a few examples (but not this 1000 Fuzz circuit but another fuzz circuit) and he could hear some differences. I have to adapt my breadboard version anyway to check audio anyway, and I can also use my synthesizer as 'guitar audio source' .

Comment: Do you make new music Michel? Does your band have a website or anything I can take a listen?

Comment: I play in two rock cover bands. We removed demos as they were outdated, so there are only some telephone live recordings (we play normally at small venues and festivals). We have a website, but most videos can be found on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/PeakyBlindersrockcovers/ and https://www.facebook.com/Co-incidental-204155766341066/ . Do you also have a website/FB page?

Comment: My site (original music): http://www.jamesoakwood.co.uk/

Comment: Very nice music ... I'm listening while I'm working now :-)

Comment: Just watched "Walk" and sounds of silence. Very good. Is that you hiding behind the rhythm guitarist on the right?

Comment: Yes that's me; keyboardists mostly are on the back (which is ok for me). Thanks for the compliment (and liking the band)... Trying to find out why liking soundcloud songs doesn't work.

Comment: I got my results (I hope) ... thanks for the advice to use the program and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Andy's proposed application MicroCap 12, I got to a few results:

- In the last capacitor column, closing all switches after the capacitor does not make a change.
- In the second transistor column, closing multiple collectors make a change, around 0.05V), but changing transistors also does not make a change, so I will not take that risk.
- In the second transistor column, closing multiple gates make also a difference, in the same range as closing multiple collectors.
- In the first capacitor group, closing all switches after the capacitor, change around 0.2V, so also no go.
- In the first capacitor group, closing all switches before the capacitor, does not make a change.

Conclusion:

- Transistors cannot be connected together (neither base nor collector).
- Capacitors can, but only before the first capacitor column, and after the last capacitor column.

Some pictures how the eventual circuit will be when the first of each column is selected:

[image]
[image]

Important:

The transient limits, I set to 
  - Maximum Run Time: 4 ms
  - Maximum Time Step: 0.001 ms

If the Maximum Time Step is set longer, V12 will change in all cases.